# Getting error when adding @uirouter/angular-hybrid in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-hybrid

I'm facing the below issue when executing my angular project. I have installed @uirouter/angular-hybrid as well. But still, I'm getting this error

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@uirouter/angular-hybrid" has missing dependencies:
 - @uirouter/angularjs
```

Can you please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you installed `@uirouter/angularjs`?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot install. My issue got resolved now. Thank you so much:)

Comment: The [readme](https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid) explicitly says to remove `@uirouter/angularjs`. How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using the following packages:

```json
    "@uirouter/angular-hybrid": "^12.0.0",
    "@uirouter/angular": "^8.0.0",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.26",
    "@uirouter/rx": "^0.6.0",
```

The versions are taken from the `peerDependencies` from `node_modules\@uirouter\angular\package.json` and `node_modules\@uirouter\angular-hybrid\package.json`

I'd still like to understand why these needed adding manually though.